# List of Entity Framework Code First Default Naming Conventions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to find a list of **examples** of Entity Framework's default **naming conventions**.  I gather that Tables are `<Entity>+s`  e.g. Users... Foreign Keys are User_Id  But I would like to see a list of all out-of-the box conventions - IE what entity framework is going to call my objects.

**I'm not looking for the types** of the conventions - I got that.  I am looking for definitions/examples of what Entity Framework's **default conventions** will name my database objects.  To be clear, I have not added or removed any conventions.  EF comes with a number of default conventions for generating databse objects - I want to know what EF's out-of-the box default conventions are going to name my database objects.

The reason I require this is because although I am using CodeFirst, I will be creating my database objects by hand rather than making EntityFramework generate it for me (my colleague is insisting on this).  Therefore I need to know what I should name my Tables, Columns, Foreign Keys......  So that Entity Framework will find/map them with no explicit mappings required.

Eg

```
EF Default TableName Convention
      <Entity> + 's' (e.g ***Users***) 

EF Default Foreign Key Convention
      <Entity> + 'Id' (e.g ***UserId***)   

EF Default Primary Key Convention
      ***Id***
```

Where can I find this?

Comment: Sorry If the question sounds Obtuse, people are having trouble understanding what I am after here.

Answer (score 9):

EF does not provide a mechanism to retrieve the set of conventions used. You can only [remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679253%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) pre configured conventions.

You can find the documented convention list on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Initially EF allowed you to customize the conventions but now that part is removed from API.

**Edit**

```
Convention: Table Name
Default: Entity + s (e.g Users)
```

[PluralizingTableNameConvention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.pluralizingtablenameconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

```
Convention: Foreign Key Relation
Default: Entity + Id (e.g UserId)
```

[NavigationPropertyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.navigationpropertynameforeignkeydiscoveryconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

```
Convention: Primary Key
Default: Id
```

[IdKeyDiscoveryConvention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.idkeydiscoveryconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the list you gave me is useful but I'm looking for definitions of the default conventions.  I'm not using any custom conventions at the moment.

Comment: @reach4thelasers You can find the definitions are also in that MSDN link

Comment: I'm having trouble explaining what i'm looking for...  I've updated the question with an example.

Comment: @reach4thelasers do you think we are here to do research on behalf of you.

Comment: Surely there's an MSDN page or something??  How can this not be published info?

Comment: Primary Key fields will also be recognized by {TableName}ID: "Primary key detection is case insensitive. Recognized naming patterns are, in order of precedence:

'Id'

[type name]Id"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.aspx) namespace is what you're looking for.
This namespace contains all naming conventions.