# How to configure table name and id at once

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF5 Code First, I have entities named `XXXEntity` which is based on `Entity` class, in `Entity` class there is `Id` property.

Here is the problem, normaly EF will create table for each entity named XXXEntities and having Id field. What I want is the table should named `XXX` (without Entities) and the Id should be `XXXId`. How to do that at once by using convention. I know I can override the table name, and Id name one by one. But it is a bit boring and not reusable, is there any better way to do that using convention or something on EF 5?

**UPDATE**

i read about [custom code first conventions](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions) but not sure is this an out dated page or a non implemented feature. because i couldn't found the `Properties<T>()` method on EF 5

Comment: Currently, (EF5) `modelBuilder.Conventions` hasn't got an Add method. So you can't plug in custom conventions. I would not use the XXXEntity name to start with. Prefixes and suffixes are useless. Likewise, what is wrong with database tables all having just `Id`?

Comment: Its a part of company naming convention/coding standard, we usually have `XXXEntity`, `XXXModel`, `XXXController`. about the Id too we have our own coding standard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that with EF 5, your link is a future feature for EF 6 [see here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/12/11/entity-framework-6-alpha2-now-available.aspx)

but you can do that with reflection easily, for reusability you can make it as an extension method of `DbModelBuilder`, a bit slow but it solve your case. here what you can do:

```
public static class MyCustomNamingConvention
{
    public static void ToMyDatabaseNamingConvention(
        this DbModelBuilder mb, IEnumerable<Type> entities)
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var mi = typeof(MyCustomNamingConvention)
                .GetMethod("MyNamingConvention")
                .MakeGenericMethod(entity);
            mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { mb });
        }
    }

    public static void MyNamingConvention<T>
        (DbModelBuilder mb) where T : Entity
    {
        var tableName = typeof(T).Name.Replace("Entity", "");
        mb.Entity<T>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        mb.Entity<T>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName(tableName + "Id");
        mb.Entity<T>().ToTable(tableName);
    }

}
```

Simply use it on your DBContext on `OnModelCreating` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(mb);
    mb.ToMyDatabaseNamingConvention(GetEntities());
}
```

Note:

- Remember to add appropriate namespace of the
  `MyCustomNamingConvention`.
- `GetEntities()` is a method to iterate your entity (remember to skip
  the `Entity` base class)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to remove table pluralizing:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

I cant seem to find a convention that you can disabled for the column Id name. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696316(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: sorry on my knowledge `PluralizingTableNameConvention` means remove the "s" and "ies" next to the entity name, what i want is "PeopleEntities" into "People" (remove the "Entities" not become "PeopleEntity"). is there any way to override the convention on that link? thank you anyway

Comment: Some more guidance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512900/list-of-entity-framework-code-first-default-naming-conventions

Comment: so no way to do that.. but the question is already 6 months is there any new update about that? i readed about http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions but in EF 5 i could't find the `Properties<T>()` method.