# DBContext class ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm wondering how Entity framework knows which table to connect to, based on the following code:

```
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

[Source](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string)

I know that by default it connects to LocalDB. I can specify the database to connect to by adding an entry to `Web.config` file, like this:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" 
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>
```

Now, the MovieDBContext class has a `Movies` property. Can I change its name without breaking anythig, or maybe this name is used by the framework to know which table to query?

What if I didn't add the code above to `Web.config` file? Would it create a Movies.mdf table automatically based on the name of property?

Comment: EF Connects to databases, not tables. Within the Database named "Movies" you will have a table called Movie since you have a DbSet for that. The name Movies can be changed if you like, but that is the convention.

Comment: The table name should be plurar of the entity name. Table 'cars' contains 'car' entities. So the Movies table will be created. I hope it's what you mean.

Comment: @Steve Greene: By default EF uses `PluralizingTableNameConvention` so table name will be "Movies"

Comment: Yep, first thing I do is disable that convention. My comment was more to straighten out database vs table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are usign Code First approach you can change name of  `Movies` property. Entity framework uses class name (in this case `class Movie`) to figure out table name.

By default it uses the following convention: Make a plural from class name and try to find such table in a database.

Regarding Database name: EF will try to create a database even if there is no connection string, but it will give a different name to it (e.g. `WebApplication1.MovieDBContext`).

Comment: By the way, do you have any MS page that says this? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512900/list-of-entity-framework-code-first-default-naming-conventions
     And also there are MSDN links:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962 - see example at the bottom.

      https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score -1):

If your database has been already crearted using EF it may occur errors. So try to map your newly named class to the table explicitly .

Comment: Even if database is created by EF it still uses class names rather then DbSet properties names..

Comment: It uses convetions, so if it cant match class name to table name what happens?

Comment: EF will throw exception:
 The model backing the 'MovieDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Comment: It stated that if database created by EF then changing name of  `Movies` property of `MovieDBContext ` may cause errors. However it's not true. Changing name of `Movies` property will NOT cause an error in this case.